# How to get defined value from another defined value, python?

Tags: python

My explanation to my question will probably be very poor. But I have defined "a" to a word, this word is also defined as a definition, I want to be able to print the definition from "a" but struggling to work out how.
Here is my current code

The text file "keywords.txt" contains, carrot, apple, and orange on seperate lines.

```
carrot = 'Green Vegtable.'
Apple = 'Red or Green fruit.'
Orange = 'Orange fruit.'

input("You Ready? Press Enter Then")

print ("Here is your Keyword")
import random
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
         a = random.choice(list(f))
         print (a)
```

Now I want the definition to match the keyword,

```
input("press enter")

print("the definitions are")

print("a =" I want the definition to be placed here)
```

If this question really doesnt make sense feel free to say and I will delete it. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to achieve what you want you need to use a dictionary. A dictionary allows you to use
keys:values. In the case I described below. `key = 'Orange'` and `value = 'Orange fruit'`

see [here](http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries) for more info on dictionaries.

```
keywords = {'carrot': 'Green Vegetable.',
            'apple': 'Red or Green fruit.',
            'Orange': 'Orange fruit.'}

print ("Here is your Keyword")
import random
with open('keywords.txt') as f:
     a = random.choice(list(f))
     print("a =", keywords[a])
```

Comment: If 'a' was defined to orange, and I did this, 'a' would just print as orange, yet I want to definition of orange to be printed.

Comment: See updated answer you need to use a dict to get that functionaly

Comment: Isn't the code a ='carrot' defining a to the value carrot? What if a happened to be apple?

Comment: well as long as `apple` is one of your keys in the dictionary then yes you will get whatever the value for the key=apple is.

Comment: print("a =", definitions[a])
KeyError: 'apple\n'

Comment: well yeah, the keys are case sensitive so if it's `apple` in your text file, not `Apple`, then it needs to be `apple` in the dict.

Comment: you have `Apple = 'Red or Green fruit.` see how it is capitalized and in your text file it is `apple`

Comment: They are identical, I have one text file for the definitions, and one for the keywords, should they both be in the same .txt file?

Comment: Then how did you get that? `print("a =", definitions[a]) KeyError: 'apple\n'` the error is because `a = 'apple\n'` not `Apple` you also need to remove the `\n` otherwise they wont match.

Comment: Just to clarify, keywords.txt should only contain the keywords and the the definitions?

Comment: And how would I rid of the \n?

Comment: All you need is the keywords, but they need to be 100% identical and I suggest you search for that answer in Stackoverflow.

Comment: Sorry for the bother, this does work, however I needed to add     .strip(), to   a = random.choice(list(f)),   so  a = random.choice(list(f)).strip()

Answer (score 0):

I think I get what you're saying and the answer is that you generally don't want to do this.  Use a dictionary instead:

```
keywords = dict(carrot = 'Green Vegtable.',
                Apple = 'Red or Green fruit.',
                Orange = 'Orange fruit.')
```

Now you can print the value:

```
a = 'carrot'
print keywords[a]
```

---

For the sake of completeness -- you don't actually *have* to use a dictionary here.  You could get it from the `locals` (or `globals`) function:

```
carrot = 'foo'
a = 'carrot'
keywords = locals()
print keywords[a]
```

However, this is not accepted as a good practice in programming so I highly recommend that you don't do it this way.

Comment: My problem is, 'a' might not always be 'carrot' as it randomly changes every time the program starts.

Comment: @user2997652 -- That's fine.  I hard-coded `a = 'carrot'` for illustration purposes.  As long as `a`'s value is one of the dictionary keys ('carrot', 'Apple', 'Orange') it doesn't matter.

Comment: Isn't the code a ='carrot' defining a to the value carrot? What if a happened to be apple?

Comment: @user2997652 -- Saying "what if `a` happened to be apple` is ambiguous.  Do you mean "what if `a = "Apple"`?  If that's the case, you're still fine.

Comment: This code defines 'a' as carrot, so if I tell python to print 'a' it will print carrot. 'a' might not always = carrot...

Answer (score 0):

Short answer is globals

```
a = 'apple'
name = 'a'
print globals()[name]
```

Comment: Short answers aren't always the best answers :).  If you give someone a gun, it's generally your responsibility to teach them how to avoid shooting themselves (or someone else!) in the foot.

Comment: @mgilson I trust people can learn by themself, just need some hint sometime. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Put your keywords in a dictionary as keys, and your definitions as values in the same dictionary.  Then lookup the keyword in the dictionary and display the associated value.

EG:

```
#!/usr/local/cpython-3.3/bin/python

dict_ = {}
dict_['carrot'] = 'Green Vegtable'
dict_['apple'] = 'Red or Green fruit'
dict_['orange'] = 'Orange fruit'

input("You Ready? Press Enter Then")

print ("Here is your Keyword")
import random
with open('keywords.txt') as file_:
    keywords = [ line.rstrip() for line in file_ ]

random_keyword = random.choice(keywords)
print('{} is {}'.format(random_keyword, dict_[random_keyword]))
```

Comment: Why the underline at the end of the variable name?

Comment: file is a builtin; creating a variable with the same name obscures the original.  file_ is not a builtin.

Comment: OK - I prefer using names that are not built-ins. I guess that adding an underscore is a valid approach too.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the definition stored in variable `Apple`, when the randomly chosen `a` is "Apple"?

Try this: Put all your definitions in a dictionary (which is also better when you want to add new fruits later), then look for the description with `a` as the dictionary key.

Like this:

```
definitions = { 'Carrot' : 'Green Vegtable.', 
                'Apple' : 'Red or Green fruit.',
                'Orange' : 'Orange fruit.'
              }
```

and later get the definition of `a` with

```
definitions[a]
```

Comment: KeyError: 'apple\n' -- I really don't understand why this error is showing